# Primefaces fileUpload fileUploadListener problem

Tags: primefaces, file-upload, uploader

I would like to implement a multitiple uploader in my page.
I tryed with [primefaces implementation](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fileUploadMultiple.jsf), using 2.2.1 version with no success.

The code in the xhtml page:

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{actionsContainer.fileStorageActions.uploadListener}"   
    multiple="true" label="choose" allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.pdf;*.webm;*.flv" description="Images"/>
```

And the code in backend function:

```
public void uploadListener(org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent event) throws CommonUtilsException {
        log.write("Upload.");
    }
```

I tryed to follow the explanation in the documentations, but even though, the backend function is not reached. Any ideas about what I am missing??
Thans in advance

**EDIT:**
As I could see in other threads, I add this suggestion

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" prependId="false">
                    <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{actionsContainer.fileStorageActions.uploadListener}"   
    multiple="true" label="choose" allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.pdf;*.webm;*.flv" description="Images"/> 
                    </h:form>
```

The result is the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. I needed to edit the file web.xml, adding this filter:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
<param-value>2097152</param-value>
</init-param>     
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

I found this [article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-upload-primefaces-under) very useful